# Find command modified date in output

Tags: linux

I'm using the find command `find /path/on/server -mtime -1 -name '*.js'` to get a list of files modified recently but I'd like the output to also have the date the files were modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-printf` option to find to print this if you want

```
find find /path/on/server -mtime -1 -name '*.js' -printf "%h%f %TD\n"
```

- `%h` the leading directories
- `%f` the file name
- `%TD` the files modification date

the `%p` format specifier can be used in place of `%h%f` for the full path.

You get output like

```
/path/on/server/somefile.ext 05/24/12
```

There are lots of options to the printf option so you can build any output format you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can customise `stat` to print exactly the information you like:

```
find /path/on/server -mtime -1 -name '*.js' -exec stat -c "%n: %y" {} \;
```

The way this works is that `find` calls `stat -c "%n: %y" FILE;` for every `FILE` that it finds in it's search, and `stat` prints that to your terminal.

This results in something like:

```
somefile.txt: 2012-06-13 02:11:59.208822237 +0100
```

Comment: find has a really handy `-printf` option

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
find /path/on/server -mtime -1 -exec ls -l {} \;
```